# The code comes out of the chunk in knitr texstudio

Tags: r, knitr, chunks, texstudio

I use knitr in texstudio to include my R script into my document, but the problem is my code comes out of the color chunk background
[image: like this exemple]

This is my code example

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
<<>>=

library(equatiomatic)
summary(cars)
extract_eq(lm(dist~speed,cars))
@

<<>>=
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
@

Throughout history, many people have wondered about the means of $x$ and $y$.
Today we can provide some answers. The mean of $x$ is approximately
\Sexpr{extract_eq(lm(dist~speed,cars))}. The mean of $y$ is approximately \Sexpr{round(mean(y), 3)}.
References

\end{document
```

Comment: Could you please share your complete code?

Comment: Is it only the warning that concerns you

Comment: @Dason it's just an example, if I write a long code, the same thing will happen, the code gonna comes out of the chunk

Comment: @Quinten I added it in the question, thanks for helping